# Metadata error when running WCF service as particular user

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I have deployed a WCF service that works great when the application pool runs as a particular domain user, but when I change the application pool to run as a different user, I get an XPATH error and my service doesn't even return metadata. I'm perplexed - my new user has permissions to all the service files (including config files), runs fine as an app pool identity, and database permissions don't matter because I can't even pull up a contract list.

Can anybody shed some light on this? I've attached the text of the error I get when I try to connect using the WCF Test Client. Changing the app pool to run as the first user and the test client pulls up a contract list, and I can call a method without any issues at all. Please save me!

> Error: Cannot import
>   wsdl:portTypeDetail: An exception was
>   thrown while running a WSDL import
>   extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporterError:
>   Schema with target namespace
>   'http://UsBankRtSvc.Model/2010/Service'
>   could not be found.XPath to Error
>   Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://UsBankRtSvc.Model/2010/Service']/wsdl:portType[@name='UsBankRealTimeServiceContract']Error:
>   Cannot import wsdl:bindingDetail:
>   There was an error importing a
>   wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is
>   dependent on.XPath to wsdl:portType:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://UsBankRtSvc.Model/2010/Service']/wsdl:portType[@name='UsBankRealTimeServiceContract']XPath to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://UsBankRtSvc.Model/2010/Service']/wsdl:binding[@name='DefaultEndpoint']Error:
>   Cannot import wsdl:portDetail: There
>   was an error importing a wsdl:binding
>   that the wsdl:port is dependent
>   on.XPath to wsdl:binding:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://UsBankRtSvc.Model/2010/Service']/wsdl:binding[@name='DefaultEndpoint']XPath
>   to Error Source:
>   //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://UsBankRtSvc.Model/2010/Service']/wsdl:service[@name='UsBankRealTimeSvc']/wsdl:port[@name='DefaultEndpoint']Warning:
>   No code was generated.If you were
>   trying to generate a client, this
>   could be because the metadata
>   documents did not contain any valid
>   contracts or servicesor because all
>   contracts/services were discovered to
>   exist in /reference assemblies. Verify
>   that you passed all the metadata
>   documents to the tool.Warning: If you
>   would like to generate data contracts
>   from schemas make sure to use the
>   /dataContractOnly option.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar issue. I fixed it by granting the IIS_WPG group full access to the c:\windows\temp folder on the server.