# WCF 400 Bad Request

Tags: wcf, json, browser, bad-request, http-status-code-400

I created a simple function

```
       [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
       string Start();
```

Definition,

```
       public String Start()
       {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return serializer.Serialize("Check");
       }
```

From browser using Javascript/Jquery,
http://localhost/service1.svc tells me I have created a service and all other info.. Looks fine. 
I'm trying to call this using 
http://localhost/service1.svc/Start

I get a 400 bad request for this call. I hope I'm not doing something totally wrong here. I should be able to access WCF service from browser right?
I tried looking a lot before I thought of posting. But I'm unable to get this basic thing working is frustrating me.

**EDIT & UPDATE**
Now I'm at this stage. The service page is telling me that the metadata service is disabled and is asking me to insert the following text

```
   <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
```

I inserted the text - but still it shows the same text!! This is getting too confusing now..

Comment: Do you have any payload with that status code? If no, try to turn on the option that sends error messages back to client. It is <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" /> under ServiceBehaviors/Behavior element.

Comment: It is set to true. But I do not get any payload. Just the status code.

Comment: @a.dimo is right, your specified that your method should only be called using POST method. When you request it with browser, it sends GET request.

Comment: I did not directly call from browser. I used a Jquery call

Comment: Could you post the server error message here?

Comment: Error: Cannot import wsdl:portTypeDetail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import 
extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporterError: 
Schema with target namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' could not be 
found

Comment: This error is visible onlywhen you use WCFTestClient.exe, it works from the browser now....

Answer (score 1):

Try to change POST with GET and restart the request

Comment: Nopes. That did not help. I already tried every combination - start, start(int id), GET and POST

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. I created WCF Rest Service.

I use URL which looks like http://localhost:8080/Service1/Start

Here is the code:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace WcfRestService1
{
    // Start the service and browse to http://<machine_name>:<port>/Service1/help to view the service's generated help page
    // NOTE: By default, a new instance of the service is created for each call; change the InstanceContextMode to Single if you want
    // a single instance of the service to process all calls.   
    [ServiceContract]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    // NOTE: If the service is renamed, remember to update the global.asax.cs file
    public class Service1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public string Start()
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return serializer.Serialize("Check");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I am unable to determine what is going wrong in my code.

Comment: What kind of project did you create? Just WCF Service Application (under WCF tab in VS) or WCF REST Service Application (under Web tab).

Comment: From WCF -> WCF Service application> I did some more investigation and here is what I found.. 
Cannot import wsdl:portType Details

Comment: similar to text in gray area in this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727091/metadata-error-when-running-wcf-service-as-particular-user

Comment: I'm not sure what I should do though!

Comment: Hi Sergey - I have updated the question - please let me know if you have any insight